# list & label - hide primary table values if the secondary table has no values

Tags: sql, listlabel

I try to create a Customer/Article List in List&Label.
The serious thing is that only the customer and article data should be displayed, by customers which also purchased an article.

What I have tried so far:
I suppressed data lines of the customer table and inserted the customer fields via the header of the article table (subtable).
This also works, but there are now gaps between the individual customers and I get these not removed.

How do I make it, that the gaps disappear or is there another way to display only customers with articles in the subtable?

What i want to display in List&Label as SQL-Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.[IdCustomer], a.[CustomerName], a.[CustomerNumber]
FROM [RELA_Customer_Articles] AS r
JOIN [ADDR_Customer] AS a ON a.[Id]=r.[IdCustomer]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the gaps by looking at the property "Distance before" and "Distance after" of the parent and child table. It defaults to 2mm/3mm. Simply set these properties to "0" by selecting the child table in the object window and you should be fine.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you!